# Im writing a class called discount.java and i am having issues processing negative values for quantity and price

Tags: java, exception, negative-number, discount

As I mentioned, I am writing a class called discount.java and TestDiscount.java; so far everything works but i am having issues getting the error message to display instead of the actual value when either quantity or price and negative values. Here is a little more info about the required output and what i have done so far:

The output must be of the form:

The quantity is: xx The unit price is: $xx.xx       The discount is: $xx.xx

Or

The quantity is: -xx    Quantity is negative. Cannot compute discount

Or

The quantity is: 150    The unit price is: -$15.00    The money is negative, cannot 
compute discount amount

```
    public class discount {


     int quantity;
     double price;
     public static int NINETY_NINE = 99;
     public static int TWENTY = 20;
     private static int TEN = 10, FORTY_NINE = 49;
     public static double TEN_PERCENT = 0.10, FIVE_PERCENT = 0.05, 
             TWO_PERCENT = 0.02, THREE_PERCENT = 0.03, ONE_PERCENT = 0.01 ;
     private double discount;
    // public static double discount_amount = discount * quantity * price;


    discount(int quantity, double price)
    {
          double discount = 0;
         //double d = discount;
           this.quantity = quantity;
           this.price = price;
     }
     boolean quantityOutOfRange()
     {
        return quantity < 0;
     }
     boolean priceOutOfRange()
    {
         return price  <  0;
    }
     public double getDiscount()
    {
       return discount;
    }

    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getUnitPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }



   public void calculate()
   {
      if (quantity > NINETY_NINE)
     {
         if (price > TWENTY)
                discount = TEN_PERCENT;

         else if ( price > TEN)
                 discount = FIVE_PERCENT;
        else
                discount = TWO_PERCENT; 
     }
     else if (quantity > FORTY_NINE)
     {
    // calculate discount
         if (price > TWENTY)
                discount = THREE_PERCENT;
         else if ( price > TEN)
                 discount = TWO_PERCENT;
        else
                discount = ONE_PERCENT; 
     }
     else
     {
    // calculate discount
         if (price > TWENTY)
                discount = TWO_PERCENT;
         else if ( price > TEN)
                 discount = ONE_PERCENT;
        else
                discount = 1;   
     }
     if (quantity < 0)
         {
            System.out.println("Quantity is negative. Cannot compute discount");
         }
    //double discount_amount = discount * quantity * price;  

   }

}



public class TestDiscount {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the quantity desired "
                + ", and unit price "
                + "\n(Separated by spaces)");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(input);

        int quantity = in.nextInt();
        double price = in.nextDouble();

        discount current = new discount(quantity, price);
        current.calculate();
        System.out.println("\nDiscounts:\n");
        System.out.println("The quantity is: " + current.getQuantity()+ "\tThe unit price is = $ " + current.getUnitPrice() + 
                "\tThe discount is = $ " + current.getQuantity()* current.getUnitPrice() * current.getDiscount());
        System.exit(0) ;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hint on naming: class names start with upper case letters. And of course, this is just learning, but in "real" applications, you should not use the primitive types float/double to represent money/currency. The other thing: avoid if/then/else without braces. Even when there is just one statement, you always want to do `if (whatever) { statement }`.

Comment: Note that printing out error messages using `System.out`, `System.err` etc isn't much use: you can't "capture" the fact that an error has occurred and do anything useful with it. Throwing an exception (e.g. an `IllegalArgumentException`) is a better approach.

Comment: A hint on constants: a constant NINETY_NINE is not better than just using 99. It is still a "magic number", and you still have to change it everywhere when it changes - unless you want to re-define NINETY_NINE to something other than 99, which would be much worse. Use a constant that describes what the number *means*, i.e. MAX_QUANTITY, or DISCOUNT_THRESHOLD.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the tips, i do appreciate them and will take them with me from now on, unfortunately for this assignment I was given the names and the template to use and ii had  to start from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create new method called like

```
public boolean validated() {

  boolean ok = true;

  if (quantity < 0)
     {
        System.out.println("Quantity is negative. Cannot compute 
                             discount");
        ok = false;
     }

  if (price< 0)
     {
        System.out.println("Price is negative. Cannot compute 
                            discount");
        ok = false;
     }

   return ok;
```

}

Then in `main`

```
discount current = new discount(quantity, price);
if (current.validated ()) {
   current.calculate ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, also how would I get the output to be exactly :       The quantity is: xx The unit price is: $xx.xx The discount is: $xx.xx

Or

The quantity is: -xx Quantity is negative. Cannot compute discount

Or

The quantity is: 150 The unit price is: -$15.00 The money is negative, cannot compute discount amount

Comment: Have a look at `String.format` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: meaning to display the error message where the -15 should be, so instead of having a negative for unit price we get the error but we also get to display the other info that is correct

Comment: If you use local variables in `validate` you can set the values for qtyMessage and priceMessage in the if/else blocks, then at the end of the method use `String.format` to bring it all together

Answer (score 1):

In method Calculate first check for negative values

```
if (quantity < 0)
 {
    System.out.println("error message");
 }

if (price < 0)
 {
    System.out.println("error message"); 
 }
```